# How to generate Gray codes of n bits that have at max k ones?

Tags: algorithms

I understand Gray codes have one bit change between them and how to convert between binary and gray. But given a bit length of **n**, I want to generate a series of Gray codes (all possible) that have one bit change and have maximum **k** ones.
Example: Given n = 3 and k = 2 
000 001 011 010 110 100 101

Comment: Interesting problem!  [This algorithm](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) doesn't do what you need, but might be a pointer to something: it will generate all sequences with $k$ bits equal to 1.

Comment: I actually found a number of ways to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Nice!  If you find a nice technique, you might want to put it in an answer here.  Or we can delete this question if you're happy otherwise.  Your call.

Comment: No I mean I found a number ways to do what you suggested in your link but not much on the problem asked.

Comment: Ah, OK. My bad.

Comment: Would they still be called Gray codes? With $k=1$ and $n=3$, I cannot yet imagine how one can parse 001, 010 and 100 with one-digit change without passing several times through 000.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to think it may not be possible for all n and k. Thank you anyway